# Qt Qsettings .INI only works in RUN mode and NOT in applicatin mode (.app)

Tags: macos, qt, ini, qsettings

I use a .ini file to save QSettings when the application is shut down.

```
//store url in QSettings
QSettings* settings = new QSettings("my_config_file.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings->setValue("url", str);
settings->sync();
```

I use the default save location because I need the code to be equal for the windows app and the mac app (windows app works perfectly btw).

When I run (or debug) the application from inside Qt creator then everything works fine: when the app closes, a .ini file is created and when the app is started, the data is read from the .ini file.

Now when I run the .app standalone, nothing happens, the .ini file is never created, and when it is created, it is not read from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: not sure why you use a heap object?

Comment: No particular reason.